# Unable to plot PCA data in R. Are scores defined by a given object/name to plot them specifically?

Tags: r, object, plot, pca

I have completed a simple PCA function using code that was passed down thru the institution. It outputs scores, loadings, eigen values, % eigen values, # of principal components, mean of columns, std deviation, and lastly the starting data. In the output file the scores are labeled with [[1]] before displaying the scores. I am attempting to plot these scores but I am unsure on how to take that data from this point. I assumed it was assigned to this [[1]] or something in the code defined these scores. This line of code is presented below:

```
 "#"perform pca on x
 x.svd <- svd(x);
 x.R <- x.svd$u %*% diag(x.svd$d);
 x.C <- t(x.svd$v);
 x.EV <- x.svd$d * x.svd$d
 x.EVpct <- x.EV/sum(x.EV);
 x.EV <- x.EV[1:sm];
 x.EVpct <- x.EVpct[1:sm];
 x.CumEVpct <- x.EVpct;
```

x.R is the part of the code enacting the scores but that too will not work with the plot function. Hopefully someone understands what I am struggling to ask. Any help is very appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking.  What is your plot command?  What would the plot you would like to produce look like?  And, is there a particular reason you're doing the SVD manually instead of using `?prcomp`?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Yeah in terms of using R I would say I am about as useful as a bag of rocks. But I am learning. I was given the code by a superior and attempting to do a scatter plot using plot(x[,1], x[,2]) where x is the scores but I am unable to figure out how to place the scores there. They are not defined as a variable in the code I was given. I think that was my issue. I am also unsure of this prcomp command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be:

```
pc <- prcomp(x)
plot(pc$x[, 1:2]
```

Comment: For simplicity sakes it appears you and Caffeine are correct. I however was told to use the code I had to work with. I was able to figure out the portion that contained the score data I needed luckily and plotted that. Sorry for the confusion.